# PDE with Fourier

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} & 0<x<1, \; t>0  \\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x) + 3\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) = f(x) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (x,0)=0
\end{array} \right. $$
I am following the method I was told by my teacher but I get a trivial solution, which should be wrong.

This is what I have done so far:
Using the separation of variables method we obtain the following Sturm-Liouville  problem
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
X^{\prime\prime} + \lambda X = 0 \\
X(0)=X(1)=0
\end{array} \right. $$
with eigenvalues $$ \lambda_n = (n\pi)^2$$
and solution $$ X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x) $$
and from $$T^{\prime\prime} + \lambda T = 0$$
we get that $$T_n(t) = A_n\cos(n\pi t) + B_n \sin (n\pi t)$$
Combinig I obtain that $$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n\pi x) \left( A_n cos(n\pi t) + B_n \sin(n\pi t) \right) $$
Imposing that $u_t(x,0) =0$ I obtain that $B_n=0 \: \forall n$. Up until this I think everything should be okay. My problem comes from finding the value of $A_n$. To do so I impose that
$u(x,0) = f(x)$ and solve the resulting integral:
$$ A_n =  f(x)\sin (n\pi x) = 2 \int_0^1 \left(\sin(\pi x) + 3\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) \right) \sin (n\pi x) dx$$
I also get that $A_n = 0, \; \forall n$. Which gives me that $u(x,t)=0$ when I'm supposed to be looking for non-trivial solutions, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a series right now $u(x,t) = A_n \sin(n\pi x)\cos(n \pi t)$. You are taking the wrong inner product. It should be with respect to $x$ (e.g. $\sin m \pi x$, not $t$).

Comment: @Gregory You're right! That was a mistake when posting the question, in paper I was doing it as you say. Changed, thanks!

Comment: The modes that survive should be the ones from the initial condition (e.g. $n = 1,2,5$).

Comment: @Gregory Okay, I'll try again having this in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to solve any integrals. Just as B10nicle pointed out, you simply just need to set $t=0$ in $u(x,t)$ and determine the coefficients by inspection.

After imposing the initial condition $u_t(x,0) = 0$, you obtain

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x)\cos(n\pi t).$$

Setting $t=0$ and equating the resulting espression with the function denoted by $f(x)$ yields

$$u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x) = \sin(\pi x) + 3\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x).$$

Now, by comparing the two expressions, you can conclude that $A_1=1, A_2=3$ and $A_5=-1$, and that $A_n=0$ otherwise. The solution is therefore

$$u(x,t) = \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi t) + 3\sin(2\pi x)\cos(2\pi t) - \sin(5\pi x)\cos(5\pi t).$$

Answer (score 0):

When you are given a boundary condition in terms of a function you should write U out first using U=XT.

it is worth noting that U is a superposition of this result, from n=0 to infinity.

This should give you a summation of your constant multiplied by sin(n pi x) and cos(n pi t). (sorry for the bad formatting, I'm new to the website and haven't learned how to do so yet).

When you substitute t=0 into this you arrive at a Fourier series for f(x).

By inspection we can observe the value of n to correspond to each different mode of sin, and thus find all the values for A required.